# typescript declaration file is processed even when it is not imported

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to understand the behavior of declaration merging.
I have created a declaration file that redeclares one function interface of the module.
The npm module 'schemavalidator' comes with its own typings.

I am using this module only as an example to demonstrate the behavoir. The question has noting to do with schemavalidator module.

What I have noticed is even if I do not import my declaration file the typescript still uses it.

What I'm trying to do is to use my custom declaration file only when I import it with the import statement.

Here are my 2 files

First my custom declaration file. Here I first re-export everything from npm module jsonschema.
Second I redefine just one function interface.

[image]

And here is my file that uses this redefined CustomFormat interface. Notice I am not importing mytypes file anywhere.
[image]

Notice the IDE is already complaining about wrong type.
And where running tsc command I am getting error from typescript compiler
[image]

So it clear to me that my custom declaration declared in mytypes.ts are processed by typescript even when the file mytypes.ts is not imported anywhere in my program.

This is not what I am trying to achieve. I want the definition to be redefined only if mytypes is imported with import statement in schemavalidator file and in all other files it should use the definition that come with npm module.

Is it possible?
import '../mytypes'